# Flash AS3 Pinch Gesture Support

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a Flash as3 project and need to detect a pinch (move two fingers toward each other )

does this gesture supported in as3 ?

how can i make something similar to it ?

Comment: Take a look here : [Adobe.com  : Touch, multitouch and gesture input](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html), I think you have all you want.

Comment: Look into [TransformGestureEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html) specifically, GESTURE_ZOOM

Comment: mmm thank you ...but if you mean zoom gesture it is not work like i want in my case 
 
i want to make two objects  cross by using a pinch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it isn't supported in ِAS 3 but you can use drag and drop with animation of your object

ob.stop(); // at beginning 
ob.play(); // when start drag